# How to get the File Description of a DLL or EXE

Tags: java, command-line, windows-vista, registry

I am creating a program that among other things is going to control Services. I am attempting to list the Services similar to the way they are listed in `msconfig` (the first window below).

I found where the services are listed in the registry. In Vista and Win7 the DisplayName and Description are often references. For example `@%SystemRoot%\system32\aelupsvc.dll,-1` is the DisplayName data for the Service `Application Experience`. In Win7 there is a location where these references are stored making it easy to get the correct DisplayName. But in Vista I did not find a place in the Registry where this information is stored. So I looked at the file being referenced and found that the `File Description` on the `Details` tab of the files properties would be sufficient.

[image]

So how can I get the `File Description`? I am using Java, so I prefer using Java or the Command Line top get this information.

Comment: It's stored in the version resource. You can do it through the Win32 API but I'd guess that someone somewhere has a Java API that exposes htis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version number is on the same page as the description.

so I guess this thread could be helpful:

[Get Version Info for .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918022/)

Comment: I was able to modify the code in the accepted answer to the thread you linked to, to get the information I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: @Dorothy I know this post is a bit old, but could you please tell how you did this (adapt VS_FIXEDFILEINFO)? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Good job and good luck but I'd suggest you other, probably easier solution.

Use command line utility `sc` and/or WMI. You can connect to WMI by executing script (JScript or VBScript) using `cscript` utility directly from java program or using number of interoporability tools like JaWin, Jintegra or Jinterop.

JaWin and Jinterop are open source products.

Comment: I would prefer to use something like WMI but I don't know what command will get me what I want. I tried `wmic datafile where name='C:\\Windows\\system32\\aelupsvc.dll'` but that does not have the File Description.