# Is it possible to retrieve the title of the first window an executable opens, without launching the executable?

Tags: c#, exe, file-format

I am writing a small project in c# to add thumbnail icons to a bunch of game folders on my PC. Is it possible to get the title of a window without running the program creating that window?

EG: Let's say I have a game executable installed to "C:/games/ExampleGame/bin/game.exe", When launched it creates a window called "VG 1"

I need to retrieve the "VG 1" string without actually running game.exe.

The purpose behind needing the Window title is so that I can scrape some data using the game's actual name. In a situation where the folder containing the game is assumed to be incorrect or inaccurate, and the executable is assumed to be named something generic.

Comment: No, it is not possible

Comment: `if (Random.Next(2) == 0) { new Form1().Show(); } else { new Form2().Show(); }`.

Comment: You [probably](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) want https://stackoverflow.com/q/12347215/11683.

Comment: The executable can pass any hardcoded string for lpWindowName parameter of CreateWindow API => so it is not possible. You can just grab the resources of the .exe