# How to get Windows file details?

Tags: java, windows, file

I want to get the "File description" and the "Copyright" of exe/dll/sys files, as showed in the  "Details" tab when you right click the file and choose the properties.

Comment: Possibly not a full solution, but there's a post about reading file metadata: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824027/get-the-metadata-of-a-file

Comment: In fact, I've tried the java.nio File Attributes, but it doesn't provide file description and copyright... Is there any other open_source library for it?

Comment: In Windows executables, these strings are saved in a [VersionInfo resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381058(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking of opening the file as Text, and the file details can be seen

Comment: @Jongware interesting; this means one can write a Windows-specific `FileSystem` implementation defining a `VersionInfoFileAttributeView` which would wrap the OS's native `FileSystem`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Windows API you can call [VerQueryValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647464%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get that information. [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) has a class for accessing this API called [Version](http://twall.github.io/jna/3.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Version.html).

This other question has some code samples that can get you started:

[Get Version Info for .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6918022/get-version-info-for-exe)

And this one has a C code sample of reading product name that you can translate into JNA:

[How do I read from a version resource in Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316626/how-do-i-read-from-a-version-resource-in-visual-c)

This obviously only works on Windows. If you want something portable, you might be able to use [pecoff4j](http://pecoff4j.sourceforge.net/) to parse the executable on your own. It claims to be able to parse the version information in the resource section of the PE (Portable Executable).

---

It seems pecoff4j doesn't support parsing version strings, so I [forked it on GitHub](https://github.com/kichik/pecoff4j) to add support for it. This code should now work:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.boris.pecoff4j.PE;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.ResourceDirectory;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.ResourceEntry;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.constant.ResourceType;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.io.PEParser;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.io.ResourceParser;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.resources.StringFileInfo;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.resources.StringTable;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.resources.VersionInfo;
import org.boris.pecoff4j.util.ResourceHelper;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PE pe = PEParser.parse("C:/windows/system32/notepad.exe");
        ResourceDirectory rd = pe.getImageData().getResourceTable();

        ResourceEntry[] entries = ResourceHelper.findResources(rd, ResourceType.VERSION_INFO);
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
            byte[] data = entries[i].getData();
            VersionInfo version = ResourceParser.readVersionInfo(data);

            StringFileInfo strings = version.getStringFileInfo();
            StringTable table = strings.getTable(0);
            for (int j = 0; j < table.getCount(); j++) {
                String key = table.getString(j).getKey();
                String value = table.getString(j).getValue();
                System.out.println(key + " = " + value);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It will print all the information you need:

```
CompanyName = Microsoft Corporation
FileDescription = Notepad
FileVersion = 6.1.7600.16385 (win7_rtm.090713-1255)
InternalName = Notepad
LegalCopyright = © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
OriginalFilename = NOTEPAD.EXE
ProductName = Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
ProductVersion = 6.1.7600.16385
```

Comment: Big Thanks!! That's exactly what I want

Comment: It occurs Java heap space OutOfMemoryError when I try to read some relectively big file like the ieframe.dll

Comment: I pushed a [fix](https://github.com/kichik/pecoff4j/commit/2814da662e784f94c3cc0d8cb8ac48b372dc8e58). Try pulling again.

Answer (score 0):

Not a definitive answer but here is an explanation of what you *can* try.

Note that this requires that you use JDK 7+.

Attributes defined by the JDK as standard (`DosFileAttributeView`, `PosixFileAttributeView`, `AclFileAttributeView`) don't account for user-defined metadata.

What you want is try and see whether your filesystem has support for [`UserDefinedFileAttributeView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/UserDefinedFileAttributeView.html). If you have some luck, it will; if you have even more luck, you will have your attributes defined in there.

Here is a small example on my system (Ubuntu 14.04; filesystem is btrfs). I typed this line on the shell:

```
setfattr -n user.comment -v "home sweet home" $HOME
```

You can then read this using (note: Java 8 code):

```
public final class Attr
{
    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException
    {
        final Path home = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        final UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(
            home, UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);

        if (view != null)
            view.list().forEach(name -> readAttr(view, name));
    }

    private static void readAttr(final UserDefinedFileAttributeView view,
        final String name)
    {
        final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        final CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newDecoder();
        try {
            view.read(name, buf);
            buf.flip();
            System.out.println(name + ": " + decoder.decode(buf).toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("exceptions in lambdas suck", e);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
comment: home sweet home
```

As the javadoc says, this is HIGHLY system dependent. Note that the only method to read an attribute by name is to read it into a `ByteBuffer` (nothing requires that an extended file attribute be text).

Comment: Maybe this is specific to the file format? As to a specific library, no idea. I don't do Windows...

Comment: @Boann not as far as the JDK `AttributeView` is concerned; you view a file's modification time as metadata, right? Yet it is part of a `BasicFileAttributeView`.

Comment: @fge I'm not sure. I might call that attribute data, but perhaps I'm just influenced by the JDK. Whatever it's called, I've never known the attribute views to open the file and extract data from inside it, which is where the exe version info is.

Comment: @Boann good point; however I do not believe there is anything in the API which prevents this. Bah. Maybe someone crazy will implement `VersionInfoAttributeView` ;)