# Fetch File Attribute of windows shared data using smb file path in java

Tags: java, samba, jcifs, file-attributes

I was working on the logic to ignore the file's which is created by "Microsoft" which crawling the C:\ drive as shared using CIFS ("smb://hostname:445/sharedfoldername").

I was using the suggested solution by my previous post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143382/how-can-i-ignore-ms-windows-files) (Solution was to use PEParser code. It was working fine when I was on same windows machine, but when I tried to run my application at ubuntu and from there I tried to craw the shared c:\ drive - Its was crawling without any issue if I did not use the logic to ignore microsoft file. BUT when I applied it then I could not found Microsoft file which I want to ignore.

**Can any one suggest any solution to get file's windows property from ubuntu/linux machine?**
Following code block return the company name value at windows - same I want to get from smb path.

```
        PE pe = null;
        try {
            pe = PEParser.parse(path);

            ResourceDirectory rd = pe.getImageData().getResourceTable();

            ResourceEntry[] entries = ResourceHelper.findResources(rd, ResourceType.VERSION_INFO);
            for (int i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                byte[] data = entries[i].getData();
                VersionInfo version = ResourceParser.readVersionInfo(data);

                StringFileInfo strings = version.getStringFileInfo();
                StringTable table = strings.getTable(0);
                for (int j = 0; j < table.getCount(); j++) {
                    String key = table.getString(j).getKey();
                    String value = table.getString(j).getValue();
                    if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("companyname")) {
                        if (value.contains("Microsoft")) {
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.debug("Exception caught which checking for Microsoft File " + e.getMessage());
        }
```