# java - Quick way to extract the company/publisher/vendor information from the File

Tags: java, file, metadata, mime-types

I am `crawling` `files` and `directory` from my `local file system` and trying to filter-out files based on their `company/publisher/vendor` name. Let's assume, I want to filter all files that belongs to `Microsoft Corporation`. I wonder if I could get these information from the `java.nio.file` or from `java.io.File` or from `MIME_TYPE` using `APACHE TIKA` but I am not finding any quick way to get the `company/publisher/vendor` information from the files.

I found the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23845480/how-to-get-windows-file-details) which exactly does what I want but it slow-down the whole process so I am looking a quick way to extract the `company/publisher/vendor` details.

Comment: Could you not split the workload across multiple threads?

Comment: Could you please provide a concrete example? On what kind of file do you want to do this?

Comment: Let's assume that I am crawling the whole c directory i.e. `file:///C:/` and there would be many files that belongs to Microsoft therefore I would like to skip those file which belongs to Microsoft.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html, i thick userDefinedFIleAttribute full fills your requirements.